# Rails request with current location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid Rails model, HighScores.
With several records, for example:

```
time: 12; name: Peter
time: 19; name: Ben
time: 16; name: Idokn
time: 8; name: Jan
time: 15; name: Adam
```

I want to sort this list and limit it for only the first three records sorted by `time` ascending.
But I also need to append a `rank` for each of the returned records so the output would show something like:

```
time: 8; name: Jan; rank: 1
time: 12; name: Peter; rank: 2
time: 15; name: Adam; rank: 3
```

It is an API, so the rank should be an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In your controller:

```
@top_three = HighScores.order('time ASC').first(3)
```

This will give you the first 3 HighScores sorted by ascending time.

Then in your view (assuming your views use erb):

```
<% @top_three.each_with_index do |score, index| %>
    <%= "time: #{score.time}; name: #{score.name}; rank: #{index + 1}" %>
<% end %>
```

`each_with_index` allows you to reference the index of the item in your list.  The index starts at 0, so you need to add 1 for each iteration to properly label your `ranks`.

**Update:**

You updated your question with: "It is an API, so the rank should be an attribute."

```
top_three = HighScores.order('time ASC').first(3)

top_three.each_with_index do |score, index|
    score.rank = index + 1
    score.save!
end
```

Your top three scores will have their rank value saved.

Comment: but, for this should i make a new attribute, 'rank' to the model?

Comment: Your model certainly needs to have the attribute rank on it.  It will just be nil or blank by default (so `HighScore#rank` called on a `HighScore` that does not have a value assigned to it will return blank or nil).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Model.all.limit(3).asc` or/and use `pluck(:field)`

Docs:

1. http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html
2. http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html